# Using Distinct On An Inner Object Property

Tags: linq

I have a collection of data that has a collection called Approvals in it. The Approvals object has a property call ApplicationName. I want a list of all the Distinct Approvals ApplicationNames. So if I have a list of Approvals with applicationNames of Nick, Nick, Jack, Daniel I want to return the whole approval object of Nick, Jack, Daniel. Or at least just a list of the names Nick, Jack, Daniel

This isnt working for me..

```
theApplicationNames = theData.Approvals.Select(c => new WebsiteApplicationInfo 
                                                    {
                                                        Name=c.ApplicationName,
                                                        ID=c.ApplicationId
                                                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Does it give you an empty result? Throw an excetion? Return everything (including duplicates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of the distinct names, you would use

```
var names = theData.Approvals.Select(a => a.ApplicationName).Distinct();
```

This would result in a list of all the names (presumably strings?).

One likely reason your version "isn't working" for you is that you are using `.Distinct()` on a collection of `WebsiteApplicationInfo` objects, which might not have a correct equality comparison implemented. Without knowing what you mean by "isn't working", though, we can't really be sure.

Comment: What is I want to add the ID of the Distinct ApplicationName and toss it into and object. Thats what WebsiteApplication info is for

Answer (score 1):

```
theData.Approvals.Select(a => a.ApplicationName).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you project a single property, you can just distinct on that. If you are projecting anonymous types, you either need to use the GroupBy trick or create a custom IComparer that you pass to the Distinct. You should be able to find quite a few solutions using the following search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=distinctby&submit=search